# Fast insert container

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, thread-safety

I need a container where insert is fast **and** thread-safe, because I plan to use it inside a `Parallel.for_each` instance.

Once in a while, I will scan said container and remove *every* items contained.

What's the best choice given those costraints?

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting to have key collisions? If not, then a normal `HashSet<T>` should be fine.

Comment: `HashSet<T>` is not thread safe.

Comment: No, each element will be different from the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bunch of concurrent collections in .NET 4.0: dictionary, queue, etc.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx

Comment: both yours and Darin's answers were useful. Since one can't accept two answers, I rewarded you because Darin has already 221k points :-)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx). Basically the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) namespace is worth checking. If you have unique keys, a [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) would be a great choice as it provides you a very fast access to elements given a key.

Answer (score 1):

try [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) - it is thread-safe and very fast since most operations are implemented lock-free... there are also [ConcurrentDictionary etc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287108.aspx) so I am not sure which features you exactly need.

Answer (score 0):

Linked List.  That has fast insertion, though I'm not sure if a threadsafe version exists in .NET